# Magento 2 - Adding part number to Invoice and sales > orders > view page

Tags: magento2.3, invoice, sku

I am trying to added part numbers into the invoice and order view pages. SKU numbers are pretty useless when picking stock when its all part numbers.

I have not been able to find someone who has been able to do this. I wish to add the part number in the same area as the SKU number or flat out replace it with a part number.

Any help to change this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Stock view in Orders > Sales > View:
[image]
What i would like to see:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the file responsible to render this view isvendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

You need to override this file in your module or theme.

In this file (sales_order_view.xml), the following block is rendering product related info.

class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"

and vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml is providing data in template.

Check if it can help in any way.